# How to look up what aggregate an entity belongs to?

Tags: event-sourcing

Sometimes, I need to run a command knowing only the entity ID, but not the aggregate it belongs to.

For example:

I have `Order` aggregate roots, to which `Invoice`s belong.
Then, when registering an actual payment towards the invoice, only the `Invoice`'s ID is available.

I can keep a separate table/collection, "Invoices" where each document/row just has an `Order` ID, and only ever insert to it when publishing the `InvoiceCreated` event.

(Or a general purpose `Entities` table, where each item will be something like `{type: "invoice", ag: <ID>}`, maybe throw in a `agType:  "order"`)

This feels problematic, but I am not sure how.

If this "lookup" is created strictly before publishing the event, or transactionally with publishing the event, it doesn't seem like anyone would come ask for it before it exists, getting a false positive "invoice doesn't exist" error.

However, doing this when/before **publishing** the event, vs when/after **applying** it seems unusual.

What's the standard solution here?

#### Update 1

I guess one problem that comes to mind is that since this is populated when publishing and not when applying is that a naive replay of the events wouldn't recreate this table. However, the data is definitely there in the event stream. And besides that, nuking this table is very unlikely to ever be necessary, due to its stupid simplicity. It can be kept regardless of the changes to aggregate state schema. So, this is not a strong argument against.

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the entity id, it means that your aggregate boundary is probably wrong. Commands are *always* executed in the scope of aggregate and by definition of the aggregate pattern, all entity ids are internal to the aggregate and it should never be possible to refer to an entity from outside of the aggregate directly.

In this particular case, an invoice is an orthogonal concern to an order. They might contain references to each other, but an invoice is a financial entity and order is a sales entity. Those entity types are often not only different aggregates but even separate subdomains or bounded contexts as such.

Of course, I don't know your context, but I'd suggest running the design round once more to see if your domain model is correct.

Comment: So, basically, a "frontend server" layer should find out the aggregate ID, and then issue the command with the aggregate already in it?

Comment: Anything that needs to talk to an entity inside an aggregate must know the aggregate id. All operations on a given aggregate go via the aggregate root, so you always need to know the aggregate root id, which serves as the aggregate id, and if you need to tell it to do something with a specific entity, you need to know the entity id. Still, I see that invoices and orders can be references from the outside works, separately, so I still suggest reviewing your context boundaries and aggregate boundaries.

Comment: I absolutely get how they can belong to different systems, but this is a tiny and specific(lol, what isn't) domain at the moment. So I'm getting away with more consistency than is strictly necessary.

Comment: Well, you definitely don't have to move them apart to different contexts, but it would be relatively easy to consider orders and invoices as separate aggregates. The event flow for payments will become more explicit and easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Separate table with Order and Invoice Id is a valid approach. That would make another projection that can be easiliy recreated by replaying events.
You probably already have Invoice projection table. Why not put Order Id there?

Comment: If it's truly a projection, someone might come asking for the `Invoice` before the projection is updated and get a non-temporary "Invoice doesn't exist" error. It's a race condition.